# What kind of database should I use?

Tags: database, react

I am going to make SNS APP that can chat with others. Basically, I'm going to create it using REACT-NATIVE, but I don't know the right DB for this. Can you tell me what kind of database you'll be using?

Comment: What is SNS in your context? Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_networking_service?

Comment: Where are you storing the data? On hand-phone/tablet/pc (i recommend sqlite) or a central server (I recommend MariahDB / MySql)